# De-interlace bytes

Tags: javascript, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

Given an interlaced bit sequence of:

```
ABABABABABABABAB
```

What javascript bitwise operation can I use to convert it to be in the sequence:

```
AAAAAAAABBBBBBBB
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your question. Are you having a byte sequence and you want to use bitwise operations on them, or you have a bit sequence and want to use bitwise operations on them?

Comment: Sorry, it's a bit sequence, so it would be a series of 16 bits interleaved that I want de-interleave (1010101010101010 to 1111111100000000)

Comment: Obviously that example sequence is arbitrary, so could be any mix of 1's and 0's, but I need to move all the Odd positioned entries into one block, and all the Even position entries into another.

Comment: 16 bits only and not 32 bits?

Comment: It's an entry in a Uint16Array, so I'm assuming 16?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's known as an [unshuffle](http://programming.sirrida.de/bit_perm.html#shuffle) (see also Hacker's Delight 7.2, shuffling bits).

The algorithm given in Hacker's Delight is:

```
t = (x ^ (x >> 1)) & 0x22222222;  x = x ^ t ^ (t << 1); 
t = (x ^ (x >> 2)) & 0x0C0C0C0C;  x = x ^ t ^ (t << 2); 
t = (x ^ (x >> 4)) & 0x00F000F0;  x = x ^ t ^ (t << 4); 
t = (x ^ (x >> 8)) & 0x0000FF00;  x = x ^ t ^ (t << 8);
```

Those right shifts can be either logical or arithmetic, the AND with the mask ensures that bits affected by that difference do no appear in `t` anyway.

This is for 32bit numbers, for 16 bit numbers you can chop off the left half of every mask and skip the last step.

This is a sequence of delta swaps, see The Art of Computer Programming volume 4A, Bitwise tricks and techniques, bitswapping.

Comment: This works great thanks. Just for the sake of completness, this is what I ended up with for my 16bit numbers (as per your instructions):

t = (x ^ (x >> 1)) & 0x2222;  x = x ^ t ^ (t << 1); 
t = (x ^ (x >> 2)) & 0x0C0C;  x = x ^ t ^ (t << 2); 
t = (x ^ (x >> 4)) & 0x00F0;  x = x ^ t ^ (t << 4);

Answer (score 1):

Check out this algorithm, if it's good for you:

```
function deinterlace(input) {
    var maskOdd = 1;
    var maskEven = 2;
    var result = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        result = result << 1;
        if(maskOdd & input) {
            result += 1;
        }
        maskOdd = maskOdd << 2;
    }

    for (var j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
        result = result << 1;
        if(maskEven & input) {
            result += 1;
            console.log(result);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7sbDd/1/).